# How to reference first list item inside ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to add Top Margin on the first item in the ListView. Is that possible?
Or, how can I reference first list item in the List View?

I tried

```
lv = (ListView)getListView();
View myRowItem = lv.getChildAt(0);
```

Probably, it doesn't work, because at the moment I executed it, list items didn't exist yet. I assume I should try above code in something like onPostRender event. Is there something like that in Java Android?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own adapter, and put that condition in the `getView` method. However, I'd like to know why you would want to add top margin just to the first item... wouldn't it behaves the same if you put that top margin to the `ListView` itself?

Comment: It pure design issue. I want list to take the whole screen (or working area), but when list shows up first time, I want some margin between top edge of working area and first item in the list. First I tried to add header row to create some spacing, which works fine until I started changing adapter and calling ... (that created another set of issues, and I concluded it is not the way to go)

Comment: It seems the only solution is to use GetWiew and apply margin value to ConvertView if position equal 0. The thing is I also have to remove margin value for positions other then 0 because this ConvertView is reused again. I was hoping for some more efficient solution.

Comment: Then, I realized, I don't know how to change top margin of convertView at position 0. I tried all the things that made sense to me with LayoutParams... it's crashing every time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the items, write your code wherever you set the list **adapter**.

By the way, in order to set the margin, just set `android:PaddingTop` of the ListView on the layout file (XML file).

Answer (score 0):

The best place to customize ListItems is its Adapter. Create a customized adapter for your ListView and use the getView method to decide what to do with every ListItem. See an example here: [How to repaint listview items when changing orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957634/how-to-repaint-listview-items-when-changing-orientation)