# How to repaint listview items when changing orientation

Tags: android

I'm trying to perform something like the GMail app does: when long touching several List view items their background colour is changed so that the user notices that something happened.

My problem is to keep those items visually selected (with the background colour changed) when the device orientation is changed. I tried this with little luck:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ItemAdapter adapter = (ItemAdapter)lv.getAdapter();
if (adapter == null) return;

for (Item q : mSelectedItems) {
    int position = adapter.getItemPosition(q);
    if (position == -1) continue;

    View itemView = lv.getChildAt(position);
    if (itemView == null) continue;

    itemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
}
```

I call this method from the onRestoreInstanceState() callback, but I receive a null in itemView because it seems that the listView hasn't been filled up yet, so there are no children at the moment. I tried to call this method from the onResume with no luck as well.

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. The proper way to accomplish this is the custom Adapter created to fill the view. Create the adapter providing a context (the Activity that has the information of which items should be painted this way or that way) and call it to get the items whose background must be changed. When iterating on the listview to paint, if the current item is one of those, paint it differently. Example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
RelativeLayout itemLayout =
        (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent,
        false);
    if (((MyActivity) mContext).isItemSelected(item)) {
             itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        }
    }
```